# Is there a unique positive semidefinite matrix such that $\bar{R} \phi^{\rm T} = R \phi^{\rm T}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

Let $R \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be positive definite and $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$. Assume that $p < n$ and that $\phi$ is rank $p$. Is there a **unique** $\bar{R} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that all of the following?

- $\bar{R}$ is positive semidefinite
- $\bar{R}$ is rank $p$
- $\bar{R} \phi^{\rm T} = R \phi^{\rm T}$

I know one solution is $\bar{R} = R \phi^{\rm T} (\phi R \phi^{\rm T})^{-1} \phi R$ but I'm not sure if this is a unique solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the solution is unique. For convenience, I will write the equation as $AC=RC$ instead of $\bar{R}\phi^T=R\phi^T$. Since $R$ is positive definite (hence nonsingular), we may write $A=RXR$ for some positive semidefinite matrix $S$. So, from $AC=RC$, we obtain $RXRC=RC,\,XRC=C$ and in turn $XRP=P$, where $P=CC^+$ is the orthogonal projection onto the column space of $C$.

Let $S=PRP$. Since $XRP=P$, the column space of $P$ lies inside the column space of $X$. However, as $P$ and $X$ have the same rank, their column spaces must be equal to each other. Hence $XP=PX=X$ and from $XRP=P$ we obtain
\begin{align}
XS&=XPRP=XRP=P,\\
SX&=(XS)^T=P^T=P,\\
XSX&=PX=X,\\
SXS&=SP=PRP^2=PRP=S.\\
\end{align}
Hence all four defining properties of Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse (namely, $XSX=X,\,SXS=S$, $XS$ is Hermitian and $SX$ is Hermitian) are satisfied, $X$ is necessarily equal to $S^+$ and $A$ is necessarily equal to $RXR=RS^+R=R(PRP)^+R$.

*Remark.* As you have found that $A=RC(C^TRC)^{-1}C^TR$ is a solution, the uniqueness of $A$ implies that $(PRP)^+$ must be equal to $C(C^TRC)^{-1}C^T$. This can be easily proved by performing a singular value decomposition of $C$ and I will omit the proof here.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not clear how you got "Since $R$ is positive definite (hence nonsingular), we may write $A=RXR$ for some positive semidefinite matrix $S$." I believe you mean PSD matrix $X$. Since $A$ is the PSD matrix we're trying to find, are you saying that for any PD matrix $R$, any PSD matrix $A$ can be written as $A = RXR$ for some PSD matrix $X$?

Comment: @BrianLai Yes, just put $X=R^{-1}AR^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah of course, thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify "However, as $P$ and $X$ have the same rank, their column spaces must be equal to each other. Hence $XP=PX=X$"? How $XP=PX=X$ follow from $P$ and $X$ having the same column space? Or is there something else I'm missing

Comment: I think I figured out $PX=X$. Since $P^2 = P$, it follows that $P$ acts as identity on vectors in the image of P. Then, since $X$ and $P$ have the same column space, for any vector $v$, $Xv = Pw$ for some vector w. Hence, $PXv = P(Pw) = P^2 w = Pw = Xv$. So $PXv = Xv$ for all $v$, hence $PX = X$.

Still not quite sure on $XP = X$

Comment: I suppose $XP=X$ would be similar by noting that $P^T R X^T = P^T$, so the column space of $P^T$ and $X^T$ are the same. Similarly, $(P^{T})^2 = P^{T}$, and hence $P^T X^T = X^T$, so $XP=X$.

Comment: @BrianLai $X$ and $P$ are symmetric. That $PX=X$ implies that $XP=X^TP^T=(PX)^T=X^T=X$. More generally, if $X$ and $P$ are two symmetric matrices whose product is again symmetric, then $X$ and $P$ must commute.