# Are the nonzero eigenvalues of $R^\bot$ bounded by min and max eigenvalue of $R$, where $R^\bot = R-R \phi^{\rm T} (\phi R \phi^{\rm T})^{-1} \phi R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Similar setup to this [previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493779/is-there-a-unique-positive-semidefinite-matrix-such-that-barr-phi-rm-t)

Let $R \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be positive definite and $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$. Assume that $p < n$ and that $\phi$ is rank $p$. Define the matrix

$$ R^\bot = R-R \phi^{\rm T} (\phi R \phi^{\rm T})^{-1} \phi R,$$

which is rank $n-p$ and positive semidefinite (proof in Lemma 3 and 4 of [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0005109800000935?casa_token=DMAl_DFWJI4AAAAA:6uZVeplJBkmHPEpLVVAvApo1uZonJV9ON4H1OfAVNTkuYJd4aOcv7q3DG-fPvEDXzMAEQgi8)) and also has the property that $R^\bot \phi = 0$. Since ${\rm rank}(R^\bot) = n-p$, $R^{\bot}$ has $n-p$ nonzero eigenvalues. I want to show that the nonzero eigenvalues of $R^\bot$ are bounded below by $\lambda_{\rm min}(R)$ and bounded above by $\lambda_{\rm max}(R)$ (min and max eigenvalues of $R$).

A proof for upperbound I think is pretty simple, as $R^\perp + R \phi^{\rm T} (\phi R \phi^{\rm T})^{-1} \phi R = R$, and both $R^\bot$ and $R \phi^{\rm T} (\phi R \phi^{\rm T})^{-1} \phi R$ are symmetric, positive semidefinite. So, Courant-Fischer min-max Theorem [can be used](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622747/are-the-eigenvalues-of-the-sum-of-two-positive-definite-matrices-increased) to show that

$$ \lambda_{\rm max}(R^\bot) \le \lambda_{\rm max}(R).$$

I'm not sure how to approach the the other bound, as clearly $\lambda_{\rm min}(R^\bot) = 0$ but I am interested in the nonzero eigenvalues. I'm fairly certain that the nonzero eigenvalues of $R^\bot$ are, in fact, bounded below by $\lambda_{\rm min}(R)$ based on numerical tests but I could also be mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R^{1/2}\phi^T(\phi R\phi^T)^{-1}\phi R^{1/2}$ is a rank-$p$ orthogonal projection. Hence $\Pi=I-R^{1/2}\phi^T(\phi R\phi^T)^{-1}\phi R^{1/2}$ is an orthogonal projection of rank $n-p$, $R^\perp=R^{1/2}\Pi R^{1/2}=(R^{1/2}\Pi)(\Pi R^{1/2})$ and it shares the same spectrum as $\Pi R\Pi$. It follows (from Courant-Fischer minimax principle or Cauchy's interlacing inequality) that the minimum nonzero eigenvalue of $R^\perp$ is bounded below by the smallest eigenvalue of $R$, which is positive.

Comment: Could you clarify how to use minmax principle or interlacing inequality in this case? I'm not too clear since $\Pi$ is a square ($n \times n$) projection matrix of rank $n-p$ rather than a $(n-p \times n$) semi-orthogonal matrix as I've typically seen the interlacing inequality stated with

Comment: @BrianLai This is straightforward. Let $W$ be the range of $\Pi$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lambda_{n-p}(\Pi R\Pi)
&=\max_{\substack{V\subseteq\mathbb R^n\\ \dim V=n-p}}\min_{\substack{u\in V\\ \|u\|=1}}u^T\Pi R\Pi u\\
&\ge\min_{\substack{u\in W\\ \|u\|=1}}u^T\Pi R\Pi u\\
&=\min_{\substack{u\in W\\ \|u\|=1}}u^T Ru\\
&\ge\min_{\|u\|=1}u^\ast Ru\\
&=\lambda_\min(R).
\end{aligned}
$$...

Comment: ...Alternatively, let $\Pi=QDQ^T$ be an orthogonal diagonalisation, where $D=I_{n-p}\oplus0$. Let $S$ be the leading principal $(n-p)$-rowed submatrix of $Q^TRQ$. Since $R\succ0$, we have $Q^TRQ\succ0$ and in turn $S\succ0$. Therefore
$$
\lambda_{n-p}(\Pi R\Pi)=\lambda_{n-p}(QDQ^TRQDQ^T)=\lambda_{n-p}(DQ^TRQD)=\lambda_{n-p}(S\oplus0)=\lambda_\min(S)
$$
and $\lambda_\min(S)\ge\lambda_\min(Q^TRQ)=\lambda_\min(R)$, by Cauchy's interlacing inequality.